# Not able to load the project after xamarin update

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin

After updating my Xamarin to the latest version. My iOS project is not getting loaded. I am getting the following error. Any Suggestions?

Error while trying to load the project '/Projects/mAuth/ios9/FP.Auth.IOS_EDC/FP.Auth.IOS/FP.Auth.IOS.csproj': '', hexadecimal value 0x10, is an invalid character.

My Xcode Version is 8.2.1

Comment: Open up your `.csproj` in a text editor and see if there's an invalid character inside somewhere.

Comment: I removed those characters but still I get an  error                                                 Error while trying to load the project '/Projects/mAuth/ios9/FP.Auth.IOS_EDC/FP.Auth.IOS/FP.Auth.IOS.csproj': Unknown solution item type